# Updating db server with no internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, apt

I have a database server running Ubuntu 12.04.  The db server is connected to a load-balancer(HAProxy) on a LAN network and the LB is connected to the internet.  So the db server has no direct internet connection.  I connect to the db server by SSHing through the load-balancer.

Is there a good way to install updates on the database-server eventhough it doesn't have a direct connection to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install and use [Apt-Cacher NG](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) on your load-balancer (or another box that is accessible to both networks) and configure apt to use that as a proxy.

To install Apt-Cacher NG:

`sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng`

To configure an apt proxy, create a file at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy` with this contents (replace the IP with your load-balancer's IP as it appears to your database servers):

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.50.2:3142";`

Apt-Cacher NG will act as a caching proxy and will only cache packages that have been requested, so it's a lot neater (and more transparent) than running your own repository.

You can tweak/configure it using the `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf` file but the default configuration will work for the majority of cases.

Comment: Note that the default `apt-cacher-ng` port is `3142`. Other than that, thank you Craig!

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own repository server and setup new repository server path on your DB servers and than you can apply update on your servers with no internet connection.

Note:- Your Repository server should be in LAN.